# How to add in Forlus R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a quick question. I want to take the average of each 12 elements in a series. I have the folowing code:

```
PPrateav = NULL
for (i in 80) {
    PPrateav[i] = sum(PPrate[1+(i-1)*12:(i*12)])/12
}
```

I cannot see where the problems is. Thanks.

Comment: E.g.: for (i in 1:80), you have to give a range of values

Comment: What is `Forlus`? Seems like you're looking for rolling average. Have you looked at the `rollmean` function from `zoo` package? Ex: `rollmean(PPrate, k=12)` (or) `rollapply(x, width=12, mean)`

Comment: maybe `Forlus` is meant to be `for loop` but misspelled. I'm guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick

```
library(zoo)
PPrateav <- rollapply(PPrate, width=12, mean, by=12)
```

See `?rollapply` for further details on `width` and `by` arguments.

If you really want to use the `for` loop, then try changing your original loop to this new version:

```
PPrateav <- NULL
for (i in 1:floor(length(PPrate)/12)) {
  PPrateav[i] = mean(PPrate[(1+(i-1)*12):(i*12)])
}
```